# Clarification on sendRedirect in sevlets

Tags: java, servlets

here i have created a form which has an input field and submit button. The submit buton should redirect to the Google search. but i'm getting error Here is my code.

MySearcher.java

```
package com.aba.examples;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MySearcher extends HttpServlet {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        response.sendRedirect("https://www.google.co.in/#q="+name);
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>sendRedirect example</title>
</head>
<body>


<form action="MySearcher">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="Google Search">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>GoogleSearcher</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>MySearcher</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MySearcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MySearcher</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MySearcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MySearcher</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class MySearcher
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MySearcher
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `<servlet-class>com.aba.examples.MySearcher</servlet-class>` missing package name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace  `<servlet-class>MySearcher</servlet-class>` with the exact package name `<servlet-class>com.aba.examples.MySearcher</servlet-class>`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing package name of servlet `MySearcher` in `<servlet-class>`
Try replacing `<servlet-class>MySearcher</servlet-class>` with `<servlet-class>com.aba.examples.MySearcher</servlet-class>`